# NextJS add dynamic seo data

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs project and I'm using static export. While a static page rendering, the page SEO options retrieves from CMS. I want to write the SEO data to exported HTML content. So, the page has 3 SEO data.

seo.header | seo.body | seo.footer

I can add the seo.header data to the head tag with next/head but I can not add the seo.body data to start of the body tag content and seo.footer data to end of the body tag content. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Does the content not get added at all to the HTML or does it get added at the wrong place? Also, what do the `seo.body` and `seo.footer` contents look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to parse incoming html in seo.body and seo.footer.
If that is the only case, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://tr.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), that way you won't need to use the library and you can put the seo content in react body and footer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But, I want to add "seo.body" content to the start of the body label and "seo.footer" content to the end of the body. Like the left side of the attached image (at _document.tsx file). I cannot do this with "dangerouslySetInnerHTML". This attribute can be applied only to an HTML label.